# Holomorphic automorphic/cusp forms on real Lie groups

Tags: nt.number-theory, lie-groups, modular-forms, automorphic-forms

An automorphic form on a real Lie group $G$ for a discrete subgroup $\Gamma$ is a function $f:G\to\mathbb{C}$ with some properties (see Borel’s definition in Proceedings of Symposia in PURE MATHEMATICS in 1965 & 1977).
It can also be defined on the Hermitian symmetric domain $D=G/K$ with the canonical automorphic factor once we assume $D$ is a complex manifold (see Harish-Chandra realization).

Is there any materials for holomorphic automorphic/cusp forms on the domain $D$? Just as what we have for the classical ones for $SL(2,\mathbb{R})$ that we have an algebra-structure and basis.

How about the integral automorphic forms given in Baily-Borel compactification? The cusp forms there are not very clear.

Comment: What you call a "domain" is really called a "symmetric space". Most symmetric spaces are not complex manifolds, so the term "holomorphic function" makes no sense on them.

Comment: Thank you. I forgot to mention the complex structure and have edited it.

Comment: The facts you mention of an algebra structure and basis just follow from the definition and Riemann-Roch also in the general case. If you would like to have also arithmetic structure, I would recommend reading on Shimura Varieties (e.g. the notes by Milne).

Comment: @assaferan Thank you. But it seems that the domain is a higher dimensional projective variety instead of a surface under $SL_2$ case. So what should I apply for the space of holomorphic cusp forms on the domain?

Comment: @Jun you're welcome. I'm not sure what is your question. You have the definition of an automorphic form above. Do you wish to understand what are the cusp forms? This is also given in the talks in the same symposium - see e.g. Section 1.8 in "automorphic forms and automorphic representations" by Borel and Jacquet. If you are asking about the algebra structure, this is simply the natural one inherited from being functions, and one checks that all the conditions are satisfied. If you ask about finite dimensionally, then there are two ways to consider that - see below.

Comment: @ Jun. Continued - First way is to consider the forms as sections of a line bundle on the space. Then being a cusp form amounts to a certain vanishing condition on the boundary. (given by the Satake compactification), and these are just finite-dimensionality results on global sections of certain line bundles, obtained through Riemann-Roch.

Comment: The second approach is to consider instead the representations these forms give rise to in the Hilbert space of L^2 functions on the space. These are indexed by representations of G whose JH constitutents can only have weights in the subcone dominated by the weight you consider, and whose multiplicity is bounded. (Thus showing finite-dimensionality of the space).

Comment: @assaferan Thank you so much! I totally understand what you mean. Let me make my question clear. The a.f.(automorphic forms) on $G$ are in correspondence with the a.f on $G/K$ if we fix the canonical automorphy factor, say $F\mapsto f$. And $f$ is holomorphic iff $Y\circ F=0$ for all $Y\in\mathfrak{n}^-$. We may call $f$ a cusp form if $F$ is (whose def is well-known). My main question is about the holomorphic cusp form $f$ such as the existence and basis,.etc.

Comment: @assaferan  BTW, is this def of c.f coincides with the one in the paper by Baily-Borel in 1966 on compactification. Does the def of  integral a.f there implies holomorphic?

Comment: @Jun - yes, this is almost a tautology. Since the analytic structure is constructed in this paper by Baily and Borel, by setting the holomorphic maps  on it to be the integral automorphic forms. (See section 10)

Comment: The existence and basis also follow from Baily-Borel theorem 10.14.

Comment: @assaferan Thank you so much! I got it now. I have a last question: is the definition of cusp forms given in 8.10 of Baily-Borel ‘s paper coincides with the canonical ones on the group given by integral over uni-radicals of parabolic subgroups, after dividing the automorphy factors? I still cannot find the equivalence or relevant materials.

Comment: @Jun: It does. Note that the rational boundary components correspond to the parabolic subgroups, and by definition of the operator Phi, it is given by integrating over the unipotent radical (modded out by the discrete subgroup).

Comment: @assaferan Thank you for your patience. I still cannot figure out where is the integration in the def of Phi. For a rational boundary components F, its normalizer N(F) is a parabolic subgroup. But the def of Phi is the collection Phi_F of auto-form on F. I guess Phi_F(w) should be an integral of ${J^-m}w$ over the uni-radical (so that it gives something cuspidal). And I don’t think Baily-Borel involved too much on integration (seems only in 5.4 but over some Lie group H).

Comment: @Jun: There is no integration in the definition, but these definitions are equivalent by performing Fourier analysis on the unipotent radical of N(F). Maybe a good example to start with are Siegel modular forms. Here, our group is GSp(2g), the space is a quotient of the Siegel space H_g, and the Siegel operator Phi, corresponding to the maximal Siegel parabolic (and the H_{g-1} boundary component) is obtained by taking the limit along an imaginary axis orthogonal to H_{g-1}. Exercise : show that Phi(f) = 0 iff its Fourier coefficients at semi-definite n which are not definite vanish.